# how to include index number in a class name

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am making a program where I need to loop through an array with a list of letters. I want the letters to be shown on their specific label. I have therefore created an outlet of each (about 38) and given them the name "alif01", "alif02", etc.

```
for (int i = 0; i < [arabicLetters count]; i++) {
    int num = i;    
    NSString *letterString = [arabicLetters objectAtIndex:i];
    NSLog(@"alif0%d is %@", num, letterString);
    alif0**[i]**.text = arabicLetters[i];
}
```

is it possible to use the index `[i]` instead of writing it all manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with below code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [arabicLetters count]; i++) {
    NSString *letterString = [arabicLetters objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString *propertyName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"alif0%d.text",i];
    [self setValue:letterString forKeyPath:propertyName];
}
```

Comment: "'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<ViewController 0x146d08d90> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key alif00.'"

Comment: create property for all the outlets. Also check if you have name alif00 or alif01. If it is alif01 then start the loop from i= 1.

Comment: You probably don't want the `0` in the name, rather it should be in the format specification for the parameter, otherwise when i gets to 10 the resulting string will be `alif010` which either won't match or is bad naming.

Answer (score 3):

You should not have 38 `IBOutlet` properties for this. You should have an array (possibly an `IBOutletCollection`) so that you can loop over the array / index into the array.

While technically you can create a key name and use KVC `valueForKey:` (appending strings / string format), the array approach is a much better solution.

Indeed, as you already have a loop, you would be better served by creating the labels in the loop directly, then you know you have the correct number. This is particularly beneficial later, when you change the contents of `arabicLetters` (though that sounds like it isn't a concern in this particular case).

Comment: I will try to use an IBOutletCollection in future programs!

Comment: Why not start now? Creating property names with a string format is nasty and inefficient. If you have intentions to do things better, start sooner rather than later ;-)